# Issue with the file sequence in the updated msi while creating patch

Tags: wix, msp

I am facing an issue in creating a patch.
The released product was created using WIX and I am creating a patch using msimsp.
The released product has many mergemodules.
The main issue is when a new file is added in patch then file sequence in the file table for many existing files is modified which is causing issue when a lower patch sequence hotfix is installed on top of this msp.
I know that installshiled does provide the facility to keep file sequence same as previous msi (released) in release tab.In release I can give path of the previous msi and when the updated msi is build then file sequence does not change.
please help to solve this issue.

Regards,
Tadul Shah.

Comment: What problems are you facing exactly? I work in a similar kind of  environment. If you could let me know your exact problem, i could try to see if i can help.

Comment: The problem i am facing is regarding the file sequence in the updated msi.For creating a patch the we are using wix to create .pcp and msimsp to create .msp.Because file sequence of the existing files change, when a lower patch sequence hf is installed on this msp, files are not getting delivered which are nor common between these 2 hfs.

Comment: Ok...Whats the issue here? Are you experiencing any problems applying the patch?   If so, what is the issue?  File sequence numbers do change for existing files as well when new files are added to the patch. Describe your problem in detail and we can take this forward.  Read this:   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/05/19/file-sequencing-and-how-files-are-located.aspx